# reorder a numeric column based on levels of another column

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to reorder my numeric column according to the factor levels of group column. my toy data looks as following:

```
toy.df  <- data.frame(group = c(rep("C",3), rep("B", 2),rep("A", 1)), num = c(rep(10, 3), rep(5,2), 20))
toy.df$group <- factor(toy.df$group, levels = c('B', 'A', 'C'))
toy.df$num <- factor(toy.df$num, levels = c('B', 'A', 'C'))
```

The last line of code is not working. Do you have any idea how I can set the levels of column num using levels of column group.

thanks

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you trying to do something like, `factor(toy.df$num, labels = c("B", "A", "C"))`?

Comment: Hi, Well I would like to have levels = c('B', 'A', 'C'). Actually I would like to use them for plotting I want the order of my facets to be based on group bed the labels to be the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to level order of `num` to mirror the level order of `group`, such that the levels of `num` are 5, 20, 10 then you could sort your data frame by `group` and then use `forcats::fct_inorder`. This will assign the factor levels of `num` in order of appearance:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- toy.df %>% 
  arrange(group) %>% 
  mutate(num = fct_inorder(factor(num)))

levels(df$num)
[1] "5"  "20" "10"
```

Note: this will change the order of your data frame.

---

You can also use `fct_reorder` using a custom function to reorder `num` that's based on `group`:

```
df <- toy.df %>% 
  mutate(num = fct_reorder(factor(num), group, function(x) as.numeric(unique(x))))
```

---

Alternatively, you could sort the data and then pull out the unique values of `num` which are ordered by `group` and use that to assign the levels:

```
df <- toy.df %>% 
  mutate(num = factor(num, unique(arrange(toy.df, group)$num)))
```